# Align center in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" backgroundImage="images/Login_01.jpg" verticalCenter="0"
            horizontalCenter="0"
 width="800" height="600" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" >
```

I need to align the background image in center, but its not working... its going towards to left for different resolutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set layout="absolute" for your Application
2. Add an Image component as the first child of the Application
3. Set the horizontalCenter="0" and verticalCenter="0" on the Image component

Answer (score 1):

Make canvas with this image, and center canvas.